# How to design multiple user forms and models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a website where people can look up menus from nearby restaurants.

As a restaurant, you can sign up and enter your menu. How should I design the model(s)?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :venue
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menus
```

or should I store everything (email, password, etc. ) within the venue model?

The next problem is the sign up form. With User and Venue model I have to create multiple models through a single form. Don't think that that is so user friendly.

The last problem: I also want to have "normal" user who can rate restaurants and that stuff. I think this would interfere with the User/Venue Model approach.

What do you think? How would you do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've kind of answered your first question with your third - if you want to be able to have `Users` that are not associated with `Venues`, you'll want to keep these two models separate, or it *would* interfere with your desire to have different types of users (at least with the ability to do it cleanly).  If you keep them separate, some `Users` can be associated with `Venues` (restaurant owners) and some can not (regular users).  In your case, regular users would have a nil `venue`.

One note - the difference between `has_one` and `belongs_to` isn't always intuitive (at least not to me), you might check out the [Rails Active Record Associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association) to make sure you're using the appropriate one.

If there's a lot of functionality that applies only to restaurant owners you might inherit one model from the other to avoid cluttering the base class (i.e. have a `User` model and a `Owner` model that inherits from it, or something like that).

As far as the signup form, it sounds like you want to create a single form that allows a restaurant owner to enter the info that will create their `User` and also their `Venue`.  You can use [nested object forms](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) for this - the link refers to Rails 2.3 but I'm using this feature in a Rails 3 project and everything works as advertised.